# Comparing phone numbers from a device to a database list

Tags: android, ios, compare

I am developing an app and I need to compare the phone numbers of the device contact list to a  phone number list in a database, but the phone numbers can be written in different forms like it’s described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164):

```
Number structure for networks
Country Code - cc = 1 to 3 digits
Identification Code = x = 1 to 4 digits
Subscriber Number = maximum = 15 − (cc + x) = 8 to 11 digits
International public telecommunication number for networks (maximum 15 digits)
```

So in Brazil the phone number can be written like:

> Subscriber Number 99999-9999
>
> Identification Code + Subscriber Number 67 99999-9999
>
> Country Code + Identification Code + Subscriber Number 55 67
>   99999-9999 or
>   +55 67 99999-9999

And in other countries the phone number can be written in different forms and can have different number patterns.

How can I compare the numbers from the device to the ones in the database like Telegram and Whatsapp do? Do I have to create a code to handle each country individually?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: I took a look a it and it doesn't solve the problem about the identification code.

Comment: Thanks Никита Хлебушкин. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) for Android and [libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) for Swift and they work really well.

For getting the area code of the number a use `getLengthOfGeographicalAreaCode` like this:

```
String nationalSignificantNumber = phoneUtil.getNationalSignificantNumber(number);
int nationalDestinationCodeLength = phoneUtil.getLengthOfNationalDestinationCode(number);

if (nationalDestinationCodeLength > 0) {
nationalDestinationCode = nationalSignificantNumber.substring(0, nationalDestinationCodeLength);
}
```

For comparing two number I use `isNumberMatch` method. It works fine.